# Push values into an empty array from foreach

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I have a collection of object retrieved from the database such that the output is [{"id":"5"},{"id":"76"},{"id":"33"}]. I want the output to be: [5, 76, 33].

I tried doing this using the code below but no luck. Working in laravel.

```
$UserNot = [2,3];
$allverified = array();
$verified = App\Models\User::whereNotIn('id', $UserNot)->select('id')->where('role', 'verified')->get()->take(5);

foreach ($verified as $veribadge) {
    $king = $veribadge->id;
    $allverified[] = $king;
}
```

Comment: "no luck" is not descriptive enough. What is the issue you're encountering ? is the query even returning any user ids ? or you have an error message ?

Comment: You are right, will add more detail in the future. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it directly from database using `pluck` without having to initiate a collection of User instances and looping it.

```
$UserNot = [2,3];
$allverified = App\Models\User::query()
    ->whereNotIn('id', $UserNot)
    ->where('role', 'verified')
    ->pluck('id')
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the namespace first: ‌

```
use App\Models\User;
```

For cleaner coding it is better: delete $UserNot and put the relevant code directly in the query:

```
$verifiedUsers = User::query()
    ->whereNotIn('id', [2,3])
    ->where('role', 'verified')
    ->pluck('id')
    ->toArray();
```